# Rails 5.1.4 not starting and giving me ERROR: worker mode not supported on JRuby or Windows Exiting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I tried starting my rails server but got the error message below, how can i fix it please

```
C:\Sites\sample_app>rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.1.4 application starting in development
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
  Please add the following to your Gemfile to avoid polling for changes:
    gem 'wdm', '>= 0.1.0' if Gem.win_platform?
  Please add the following to your Gemfile to avoid polling for changes:
    gem 'wdm', '>= 0.1.0' if Gem.win_platform?
ERROR: worker mode not supported on JRuby or Windows
Exiting
```

Comment: have you installed `devkit`?

Answer (score 5):

According to [this](https://github.com/MartinStyk/quotes-recommender/issues/4) issue page for Puma, it can be resolved by commenting out the following line in `puma.rb`:

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
```

Comment: If I am understanding this correctly, the application may now work slowly. I have tested this in Ubuntu vs Windows. With Ubuntu, we can leave this line uncommented and use Rails with better performance. 

A Better solution is required.

Answer (score 2):

According to the same [issue](https://github.com/MartinStyk/quotes-recommender/issues/4)  page for Puma, for the newer versions of rails , it can be resolved by commenting out the following line in `puma.rb`:

```
# workers ENV.fetch("WEB_CONCURRENCY") { 2 }
```